# Understanding the definition of integral surface

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have

$$ a u_x + b u_y = c $$

Im given the following definition: ${\bf integral \; surface}$ for the pde above is the set

$$ \Sigma = \{(x,y,z) \in U \subset \mathbb{R}^3 : z = u(x,y) \} $$

where $U$ is open.

Question: In my notes, I read the following sentence:

Suppose $z = u(x,y)$ is an integral surface  of the vector field V=(a,b,c).

What do they mean by that? I see in the definition of integral surface to be the solution of the pde, but what do they mean by integral surface of the vector field?

Comment: This just means that the vector field is everywhere tangent to the surface, that it's a genuine vector field on the surface, not just an arbitrary vector field on the ambient space which you restrict to the surface, and have some parallel and some perpendicular parts. It is all tangent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $z = u(x,y)$ is a solution to
$$
a u_x + b u_y = c  \ \ \ (*),
$$
then $z$ is called the integral surface of $(*)$. Moreover, the vector (field) $V = (a,b,c)$ is called the characteristic direction of $(*)$. We see why after simple rearrangement of $(*),$ which can be expressed as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
u_x \\
u_y \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c
\end{pmatrix}
=
0.
$$
$(*)$ in this form has a more visible geometric meaning. The normal direction of $u$ at each point is orthogonal to $V$. That is, $V$ is, at every point, tangent to the surface $u$.